# How to filter column output based on specific format value

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

Is there any way to filter by the output format in sql server.

Below is my output :

> SQLOutput
>
> AB-123456-99 Checker
>
> 123456-10000-00 2016
>
> 111119-20000-00 2016

How can I get the expected output as below,

the query should exclude all the column values which are in the format

> 123456-10000-00  -- xxxxxx-xxxxx-xx

If the column output has this format that value should be excluded from results.

and my final output should be as below :

> SQLOutput
>
> AB-123456-99 Checker

Please help if there is any way to get this.

Comment: Your example in contradictory.  `123456-10000-00 2016` does not have a `-` between `00` and `2016`. Then you said exclude any with format `123456-10000-00 -- xxxxxx-xxxxx-xx`.  Is all your output will have `AB`  (or any 2 English alphabets) at the beginning and `Checker` at the end? Does case matter?

Comment: Add'l questions: Are you looking to eliminate *rows* where the first column is like `xxxxxx-xxxxx-xx`, *rows* where *any* column matches said pattern, or leave rows in place, blanking out *columns* that match the pattern. I'm assuming the first option, but your question as stated isn't clear. In your examples, are `2016` and `Checker` a second column, or part of the first column? If part of the first column, then are you looking for columns that *start* with the pattern? that *contain* the pattern? Also - DDL for the table(s), and the current query would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your output is all one column, I would go with the conditional clause below. If you output is more than one column, then you can make the adjustments accordingly.

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
(Column1 VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @table
        ( Column1 )
VALUES  ( 'AB-123456-99 Checker')
    ,('123456-10000-00 2016')
    ,('111119-20000-00 2016')


SELECT t.Column1 FROM @table AS t
WHERE t.Column1 NOT LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]%'
```

So, you would essentially replace the `x` with `[0-9]` for numeric. If it was alpha, you would replace the `x` with `[a-z]` for case insensitive collations and `[A-Za-z]` for case sensitive collations. If it's alpha or numeric, it would be `[0-9a-z]` or `[0-9A-Za-z]`